# Problematic behaviour of either error bars or geom_text labels in ggplot with dodged bars of equal width

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text, position-dodge

I have a problem getting a plot right with the geom_text labels and the error bars in the correct position.
Mock example:

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)

# Mock data for ggplot
incidence_table <- data.frame(
  stage = sample(c("Stage1", "Stage2", "Stage3", "Stage4"), size = 21, replace = T),
  ageGroup = factor(sample(c("AgeGroup1", "AgeGroup2", "AgeGroup3", 
                               "AgeGroup4", "AgeGroup5", "AgeGroup6"), size = 21, replace = T)),
  Incidence = sample(500:1000, size = 21, replace =T),
  patients = sample(30:100, size = 21, replace = T)
)

incidence_table$IncUpper <- incidence_table$Incidence + sample(30:60, size = 21, replace = T)
incidence_table$IncLower <- incidence_table$Incidence - sample(30:60, size = 21, replace = T)


# Create the ggplot
b <- ggplot(incidence_table, aes(x = factor(stage), y = Incidence, fill = factor(ageGroup))) + theme_bw()

# Add columns
b <- b + geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = 'single'), colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_brewer("age group", palette = "Oranges") + xlab("stage") + ylab("Incidence of event") +
  geom_text(aes(label = patients, y = -60 ), size = 5, position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  geom_errorbar(data = incidence_table, aes(x = factor(stage), ymin = IncLower, ymax = IncUpper),
                position = position_dodge2(width = .9), width = 0.25, color = "black")


# Print the plot
print(b)
```

I have tried `position_dodge()` and `position_dodge2()`, but was not able to get the error bars and the text labels below the bars in the correct position

Comment: in your example data you can have two different bars within each stage with the same age group. is this intentional?

Comment: no, in the original data it is not like this. There is only one age group in every stage.  I ve just quickly coded a minimum example

Comment: My answer addresses the immediate question.  Using facets might be a better approach but will only work well with one observation per age group per stage so if you fix your example I can demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why using the `width` argument to `position_dodge2` doesn't work (maybe somebody else can explain) but the way to do this is with the `padding` argument to reduce the errorbar widths (keeping the `width` of the error bars the same as the columns).  So:

```
# Create the ggplot
b <- ggplot(incidence_table, aes(x = factor(stage), y = Incidence, fill = factor(ageGroup))) + theme_bw()

# Add columns
b <- b+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = 'single'), colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_brewer("age group", palette = "Oranges") + 
  xlab("stage") + 
  ylab("Incidence of event") +
  geom_text(aes(label = patients, y = -60 ), size = 4, position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = IncLower, ymax = IncUpper),
                position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single",padding=0.7), 
                width = .9, 
                color = "black")


# Print the plot
print(b)
```

[image]

Personally though I think I'd use `facet_grid` for this instead of dodging.  With your new example data in the comments:

```
ggplot(incidence_table) + 
  aes(x=factor(ageGroup), y=Incidence,fill = factor(ageGroup)) + 
  facet_grid(~stage, scale="free", space="free") + 
  geom_col(color="black", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer("age group", palette = "Oranges") + 
  xlab("stage") + 
  ylab("Incidence of event") +
  geom_text(aes(label = patients, y = -60 ), size = 4) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = IncLower, ymax = IncUpper), 
                width = .25, 
                color = "black")  + theme_bw()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

The `scale="free", space="free"` arguments will make the panels change size depending on which age groups are present at each stage.

Comment: `incidence_table <- data.frame(
  stage = rep(c("Stage1", "Stage2", "Stage3", "Stage4"), each = 6),
  ageGroup = factor(rep(c("AgeGroup1", "AgeGroup2", "AgeGroup3", 
                               "AgeGroup4", "AgeGroup5", "AgeGroup6"), times = 4) ),
  Incidence = sample(500:1000, size = 24, replace =T),
  patients = sample(30:100, size = 24, replace = T)
)

incidence_table$IncUpper <- incidence_table$Incidence + sample(30:60, size = 24, replace = T)
incidence_table$IncLower <- incidence_table$Incidence - sample(30:60, size = 24, replace = T)`

Comment: that would be an example, which is almost like the real data except for that age groups might be missing in some stages

Comment: i've added a `facet_grid` example